# Android Studio GridLayout not working. Shows completely grey into Design View

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-gridlayout

I hope someone can help me with this :S

I am working on Android Studio 3.6.2 and Gradle version is 5.6.4.

I just tried to drag and drop a GridLayout into a ConstraintLayout. But for some reason the **GridLayout shows completely grey.**

I read in my research that could be something related with the Gradle files. I read I need:

1) `implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'`

2)

```
repositories {
        google()
    }
```

I have these two included in my Gradle files. So, am I missing something somewhere?

I upload a reference image and some code. Thanks in advance ;)

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejTq1.jpg)

build.gradle (Project: AndroidSample)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aretius.androidsample"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
}
```

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You can directly paste a screenshot onto Stackoverflow. Including images inline would help with reading the question.

Comment: I would like but it says "You're not allowed to embed images in your posts yet, so we've included a link instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally solved my problem reinstalling Android Studio with the latest version of it :)